# Draw graph for child nodes on click of the node of tree pattern in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am using tree layout to plot the graph. On double click of the child node in the graph(loaded initially from json object), it will use the **jsonChild** object in the sample project(json data for child node usually we will get using ajax call from db) to plot graph in tree format. Issue that i am facing is, i am losing the graph from json object. I am getting graph replotted for jsonChild object only. I have created a [sample jsfiddle project](https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/1v3rz0fw/2/). I am newbie in d3.js, please help me out.

```
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d){ 
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
    });

// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
    .on("click", click)
    .on("dblclick", getprofile);

nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("fill", function(d){ 
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
    }); 
function getprofile(){
    root = jsonChild;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
     root.children.forEach(collapse);
    function collapse(d){
         if (d.children){
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
         }             
    }               
    update(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
function getprofile(){
    root = jsonChild;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
     root.children.forEach(collapse);
    function collapse(d){
         if (d.children){
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
         }             
    }               
    update(root);
}
```

The reason why you see child replace the old root is because you doing:

```
root = jsonChild;
```

The correct code should have been this:

```
function getprofile(d) {
    //here d is node which you have double clicked.
    //to that node add the children array.This array can be fetched from Ajax as you were mentioning you want to do.
    d.children = jsonChild.children; 

    update(root);
}
```

Comment: It's working, thanks Cyril once again to help me out.